# SQL: How to split a string at each character to display in a separate row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to split a string at each character and display each of them in a separate row. I also need an extra column (Col2) which should display whether the character is a number or not (if number, then 1 else 0).

Example:

If the data is 'October 11, 2017', I should get

```
Col1 Col2
O    0
c    0
t    0
o    0
b    0
e    0
r    0
     0
1    1
1    1
,    0
     0
2    1
0    1
1    1
7    1
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = 'October 11, 2017'

;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT STUFF(@data,1,1,'') TXT, LEFT(@data,1) Col1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT STUFF(TXT,1,1,'') TXT, LEFT(TXT,1) Col1 FROM CTE
    WHERE LEN(TXT) > 0
)
select Col1, ISNUMERIC(Col1) from CTE
```

Result:

```
Col1 Col2
---- -----------
O    0
c    0
t    0
o    0
b    0
e    0
r    0
     0
1    1
1    1
,    1
     0
2    1
0    1
1    1
7    1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbSeperate (Data NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO tbSeperate SELECT 'October 11, 2017'

SELECT SUBSTRING(Data,Number,1) rt , CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(Data,Number,1) AS INT) IS NULL THEN 0 
WHEN SUBSTRING(Data,Number,1) = ' ' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END c FROM tbSeperate
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE number > 0 AND number <= LEN(Data))V
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select cast('October 11, 2017' as varchar(max)) as str,
             cast(NULL as varchar(max)) as letter, 0 as lev
      union all
      select substring(str, 2, len(str)), left(str, 1), lev + 1
      from cte
      where str <> ''
    )
select letter,
       (case when letter between '0' and '9' then 1 else 0 end) as is_digit
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

If the string can have more than 99 characters, then you would want to use the maximum recursion option.

[Here](http://rextester.com/LNXMY84208) is a Rextester.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive CTE in MySQL we can achieve this.

following query will  print the character of each string in different rows.
replace your table name and column name as per requirement.

```
   WITH RECURSIVE cte
   as 
   ( 
      select 1 as n,1 as f,first_name ,'Temporary Variable' as name1  from        customer
    union
    select (n+1) as n,f,first_name,substr(first_name,n,f) as name1 from cte 
   where substr(first_name,n,n)<>""
   )
   select n,name1,first_name from cte where n<>1 and first_name='KAREN'
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RxYn.png)